# Automate calling bash commands on a Kubernetes container

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I am running an Elasticsearch stack with Kibana and Fluent Bit on Kubernetes. To set up security I set a passwords using this command:

```
kubectl exec -it $(kubectl get pods -n logging | grep elasticsearch-client | sed -n 1p | awk '{print $1}') -n logging -- bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords auto -b
```

Following [this tutorial](https://www.studytonight.com/post/setup-elasticsearch-with-authentication-xpack-security-enabled-on-kubernetes)

As during development, I have to do this setup quite often I want to automate this step, but I can not quite get it working. As I am using [Tiltfiles](https://docs.tilt.dev/tiltfile_concepts.html) my first instinct was to call a bash script from there but as `Starlark` does not support this, it is not an option. My next attempt was to try it with `Init Containers` but as they can not access the other containers this also did not work.
Does anyone know what the correct way to do this is?

Comment: I'd mount a Secret with the relevant password file.  Scripting `kubectl exec` like this is very unreliable: if a pod gets destroyed and recreated outside your control (because a node fails or is overcommitted, for example) this customization will get totally lost.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Yes, you are right I should put the (bootstrap) password into a secret. My initial problem was that I thought that the elasticsearch-setup-passwords tool was the only way to set up the (user) password. In other words, I did not know the password before the program was started.
But I just found a way to change the bootstrap password beforehand (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/built-in-users.html) so the problem is solved. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @David Maze pointed out I should put the (bootstrap) password into a `secret`.

My initial problem was that I thought that the `elasticsearch-setup-passwords` tool was the only way to set up the (user) password.

In other words, I did not know the password before the program was started.
But I just found a way to change the bootstrap password beforehand [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/built-in-users.html), so the problem is solved.

Comment: please accept your answer. You won't get points for accepting own answer but this solution will be more visible for users with similar issue.